# function only returns one value multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, function, associative-array

I have this `function`:

```
function get_content($text_to_match) {
    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM table_name ";
    $query .= "WHERE one_column_name LIKE '%{$text_to_match}%' OR another_column_name LIKE '%{$text_to_match}%'";
    $cont = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if($content = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cont)) {
        return $content;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But when I call it like:

```
  <div>
      <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i < count(get_content("text_to_match")); $i++) {
          echo '<article>' .
                 '<h3>' . get_content("text_to_match")["string1"] . '</h3>'.
                 '<p>' . get_content("text_to_match")["string2"] . '</p>' .
               '</article>';
        }
      ?>
  </div>
```

I only get the first match in the `DB` repeated as many times as the number of found items.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: what you're trying to do...please be specific

Comment: mysqli_fetch_all ?

Comment: @raveenanigam, the second last sentence mentions the intent clearly.

Comment: @splash58, I tried that but never worked

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Combined with **Unix One**'s answer, I now have a working solution (posted as an answer herein)...

Comment: @Anant, I don't have enough points for upvotes. I can't mark my own answer as accepted right away according to Stakoverflow rules.

Comment: @Dut wait for sometime and then you will at least mark your answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few modifications in combination with tips from @**Anant** and @**Unix One**'s answer, I arrived at this working solution:

***Function definition***

```
  function get_content($text_to_match, $multiple=false) {
        $query  = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM table_name ";
        $query .= "WHERE one_column_name LIKE '%{$text_to_match}%' OR another_column_name LIKE '%{$text_to_match}%'";
        $cont = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if ($multiple) {
          $content_array = [];
          while($content = mysqli_fetch_array($cont)) {
            $content_array[] = $content;
          }
          return $content_array;
        } else {
          if($content = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cont)) {
            return $content;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        }
   }
```

***Function calls***

```
<?php
  /* multiple items */
  foreach(get_content("text_to_match", true) as $content) {
    echo '<article>' .
           '<h3>' . $content["string1"] . '</h3>' .
           '<p>' . $content["string2"] . '</p>' .
         '</article>';
  }
?>

<?php
  /* one item */
  echo get_content("text_to_match")["string"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code then fetch data properly

```
 while($content = mysql_fetch_array($cont))
{
   return $content;

 }
```

Comment: @Dut not really what? You're not helping yourself at all and  not providing any sample data inputs or outputs to help

Comment: @MikeMcMahon  YOU ARE CORRECT. EVEN IN MY ANSWER I HAVE GIVEN EVERYTHING, but he is not responding

Comment: @MikeMcMahon, this answer is vague (at least to me). I wasn't sure of how to provide a sample input since the data is from a db.

Comment: @Anant, we are in different timezones, thus long times to respond... I slept after a few responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is at fault. You are calling `get_content` function to get all matches for the loop, as well as to get individual elements out of the list. This is:

- bad logic - the 2nd use case doesn't make sense
- excessive - you shouldn't need to run a database query just to output an already retrieved result

What you probably want to do is:

```
foreach (get_content('text_to_match') as $content) {
    echo '<article>';
    echo '<h3>' . $content['string1']  . '</h3>';
    echo '<p>' . $content['string2'] . '</p>';
    echo '</article>';
}
```

Comment: doesn't fit the bill, blows up!

Comment: I don't have your application to run, so you'll have to fix whatever "blows up" means. I'm merely pointing out the flaw in your logic to help you towards fixing your problem.

Comment: Integrated into other changes, this is helpful. Unfortunately, I can't upvote and it's incomplete to mark as accepted.